# Grails dealing checkbox without GSP

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, checkbox, gsp

I'm not using `GSP` files and I'm getting nulls on my `params.data` to return back to my application as `JSON`. My problem is on the grails or javascript?

**javascript**

```
var data = $('input:checkbox[name=grid-checkbox]:checked').map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).toArray();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: data,
    crossdomain: true,
    url: "http://..../food",
    success: success,
    error: fail
});
```

**grails**

```
def food() {
    def result = []
    def checkbox = params.data
    def b
    println params.data //null
    checkbox.each {
        b = Food.findAllById(checkbox.it).collect { Food food ->
            result << [id: food.id,
                    foodType: food.foodType
            ]
        }
    }
    return formatAndRender("JSON", params.callback, result)
}
```

Comment: Looks to be an issue with your jQuery. Try data { data: data }, in your ajax call.

Comment: I'll check asap when my internet is up

Comment: Be careful, I have a minor typo it should be data: {data: data}

Comment: from my alert its giving me (checked) 2,3,4 but still null on params.data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is null because no data key exists in the params map.

`data: data` should be a valid key value pair like

```
data: "data=" + data
```

Comment: I'll check asap when my internet is up

Comment: from my alert its giving me (checked) `2,3,4` but still null on params.data

Comment: Well it iterate everything, even the `,`. There's any solution better than mine `if(it != ",") ...`?

Comment: Try `params.data.split(',').each {`